# Firebase Callable Functions Caching Header?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering is there a way to cache the response from firebase `onCall` functions? just like we can on `onRequest` functions.

**How to do this inside (callable functions)?**

```
response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions SDKs offer no control over any details of the HTTP protocol.

If you need control over any part of the [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) that deviates from what's implemented by callables, you should instead use a normal HTTP function and implement those details yourself.

Comment: So, their main purpose is to do some work as background functions instead of serving content faster on page visits?

Comment: Not really background, but more like offloading work that should only be done on a backend, perhaps for security or performance reasons.

Comment: Hmm makes sense, Also, to me using them for things that do not show immediate results like create a new post in the backend and store it into DB makes more sense. Then later when you visit your profile page that post is already there to be fetched from the database along with all the other posts. Thanks for answering. 